# making parts of an image clickable for guitar tablature android app

Tags: android, clickable, clickable-image

So I want to make a simple touch screen guitar tablature creator for android but I really do not know what method to use. I am fairly new to writing apps but I am comfortable with java. 
The guitar fret board would look something like this. http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Guitar_Fretboard_Open_Strings_Diagram.png

1) At first I was leaning towards making buttons for each string and fret but I thought that may be a little difficult considering there are 24 frets on a guitar plus 6 strings (144 buttons) and each time the button was pushed it would update and array that has 6 rows and x amount of columns. I would make place the buttons on the image at the frets and make them invisible, but having the buttons line up may be tricky and they may not scale the way I would like.

An array would be pretty handy to hold the values because tablature is written like so...

```
e string -------
b string ----2--
g string ------3
d string 0-0----
a string -------
E string -------
```

the fret numbers are written in.

I am not even sure where to begin with this method. Should I have a separate method for each button because they all have different values?
To get a value from the button to the array I would need to put something like

strArray[count,n]

where count is a variable out side the method and n is the variable that is returned when the button is clicked. Count would be increased or decreased with a next/previous button so it can traverse the array

2) I was looking at this method http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/ and it looks like it could work but the developer was using colors to tell the different hot spot, and I was thinking that would probably not be feasible either considering I would need 144 different colors.

Is there an easier way that I could implement this instead?

Sorry if I haven't explained very well, I am new to developing on android and I have a lot of questions.

Comment: Am I right that fretboard should be scrollable? Or all frets should be on screen at the same time?

Comment: yes, scroll-able would be ideal, but having the image show up at the same time and allowing the user to "pinch to zoom" would also work.

Answer (score 1):

Using invisible buttons over the top of a larger background would be conceptually easy, but would have the scalability issues that you mention. It also won't handle recognizing multiple simultaneous touches very well. the The core of the second approach, using touch, is probably the way you want to go. The MotionEvent in the onTouch() method will provide you with the location and action of the touches. Then it just becomes an exercise in translating the coordinate of the spot touched/moved/lifted with the appropriate fret or string.

There are many decent tutorials available on doing touch recognition. [Here's one](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Touch_and_Multi-touch_Event_Handling).

## Edit:

There are a couple of ways to translate between touch position and the desired string & fret. One way is to just do the calculations `strng = x / (width / NUM_STRINGS)` and `fret = y / (height / NUM_FRETS)` for each touch event. (Assuming the strings are drawn lengthwise on the display.)

Another straightforward way is to build and use lookup tables to do the translation. This does cost a few thousand bytes to store the ints, but allows for a couple of fast array lookups to determine the string and fret.

Here's a sample activity that implements the latter approach. It contains some assumptions and shortcuts, but the basic functionality should is fairly sound. Only the down event shows the translation; you'll want to do something appropriate for the up and move events as well.

### MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.guitar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
                          implements OnTouchListener, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {

    final static String TAG = "MainActivity";
    final static int NUM_STRINGS = 6;
    final static int NUM_FRETS = 12;

    ImageView img = null;
    LinearLayout layout = null;

    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    int touchToString[] = null;
    int touchToFret[] = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        layout.setOnTouchListener(this);
        layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // Handle the touch event:
        int idx = event.getActionIndex();
        int id = event.getPointerId(idx);
        int x = (int) event.getX(idx);
        int y = (int) event.getY(idx);         

        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:            
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("DOWN event for pointer %d at %d, %d", id, x, y));

            // If touch is within the bounds of the layout:
            if (x > 0 && x < width && y > 0 && y < height)                
                Log.i(TAG, String.format("Pressed string %d at fret position %d",
                                         touchToString[x], touchToFret[y]));
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            for (int ptr = 0; ptr < event.getPointerCount(); ptr++)
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("MOVE event for pointer %d at %d, %d",
                      event.getPointerId(ptr), (int) event.getX(ptr), (int) event.getY(ptr)));
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("UP event for pointer %d at %d, %d", id, x, y));
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // Get the current width and height of the layout:
        width = layout.getMeasuredWidth();
        height = layout.getMeasuredHeight();        
        Log.i(TAG, String.format("The layout is now (%d x %d)", width , height));

        // (Re)build the string position translation array: 
        touchToString = new int[width];
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            touchToString[x] = x / (width / NUM_STRINGS);

        // (Re)build the fret position translation array: 
        touchToFret = new int[height];
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            touchToFret[y] = y / (height / NUM_FRETS);
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand the concept of what you are talking about, but I do not understand how I can translate the coordinates. If I presses the first string at the first fret, I know I can getX() and getY(), but how would I implement those variables?